# Cambiar fuente de texto en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Hola estoy haciendo un proyecto de un juego muy basico en python, pygame, y queria saber como cambiarle la fuente a un texto dentro de una ventana, tiene la fuente por defecto y queria saber como cambiar la fuente a cualquier otra, queria saber si me pueden dar unos pasillos para seguir es que soy muy nuevo y otra duda, esto se debe aprender por si solo o algo que te lo deben enseñar? muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es crear una variable para usar esa fuente y luego usamos la función `pygame.font.SysFont()` que tiene como primer parámetro la fuente que usaremos y su segundo parámetro hace como referencia un `int` que es el tamaño de letra.

Ejemplo del código:

```
arial = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 30)
```

Y si quieres usarlo en un texto usas el método `.render()` que si bien puedes usarlo para dibujarlo pero puedes usarla como variable, ejemplo:

```
fuente = arial.render("Probando.", 0, NEGRO)
```

El primer parámetro es la cadena o el texto que queremos usar, el segundo es el antialias, el tercer parámetro es el color de la letra y el último parámetro no visible y que está por defecto es el color del fondo de la letra.

Por último dibujaremos la letra que creamos.

```
ventana.blit(fuente, (x, y))
```

No hace falta decir que usamos el método `blit()` para dibujar y en el primer parámetro ponemos la variable que dibujaremos y se nos dibujará el texto y con tipo de fuente.

Lo más recomendado es aprender por si solo, ya sea viendo vídeos en Internet acerca de pygame o leer guías, pero lo más recomendado es leerte la documentación oficial de pygame que te dejaré abajo.

Enlaces:

- https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html (cargar y renderizar las fuentes)
- https://www.pygame.org/docs/ (documentación oficial de Pygame)